# Clear last selected position OnClick in Recycler View adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, highlight, listitem

I have a list of industries set in an adapter. Every time I click/select an industry, the name, and the background color changes. But when I try the below code, the previously selected industry does not change to its default color

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    holder.txtIndustry.setText(industries.get(position).getIndustryName().trim());
    holder.txtIndustry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            // Highlight the background and change the text color.
            if (selectedPosition == position) {
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
                holder.txtIndustry.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                holder.txtIndustry.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
            }
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
            callback.selectedIndustryPosition(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that onClick is inside each holder. I mean, each row has its own onClick. If you click on row 2, you are accessing ONLY to that holder.

One solution could be, maintain a reference to last modified holder.

```
private ViewHolder lastModifiedHoled = null;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    holder.txtIndustry.setText(industries.get(position).getIndustryName().trim());
    holder.txtIndustry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();

            // Reset last modified
            if (lastModifiedHoled != null) {
                int lastPosition = lastModifiedHoled.getAdapterPosition();
                lastModifiedHoled.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                lastModifiedHoled.txtIndustry.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
                notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
            }

            // Highlight the background and change the text color.
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
            holder.txtIndustry.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);

            lastModifiedHoled = holder;

            callback.selectedIndustryPosition(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code will overlap the data when you scroll the list

Comment: Ops, you are right. But In this case the holder is NOT recyclable. Not only in my code but also in the question.

Answer (score 0):

update your code to this it will work:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        if (selectedPosition != -1) {
            if (selectedPosition == position) {
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
                holder.txtIndustry.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                holder.txtIndustry.setTextColor(context.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
            }
        }
        holder.txtIndustry.setText(industries.get(position).getIndustryName()
                .trim());
        holder.txtIndustry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                // Highlight the background and change the text color.
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
                callback.selectedIndustryPosition(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

As on click will only call when you click on your button. Once the click is complete your adapter code will be called where you haven't written code to change the color. Initially define `selectedPosition`  to `-1` so when you load your list first time it will show the inital background color.

Comment: have you initialize selectedPosition  = -1 along with other variable of your adapter?

Comment: Yes , int selectedPosition = -1

Comment: where you define it?

Comment: It's a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your code *ONLY CHANGES* the layout from default to the selected. You never reset the layout back to default. Take a look at the code below:

On your listener, you can reset all the visible items.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    holder.txtIndustry.setText(industries.get(position).getIndustryName().trim());
    holder.txtIndustry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            // Highlight the background and change the text color.
            if (selectedPosition == position) {
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
                holder.txtIndustry.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                holder.txtIndustry.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color_blue));
            }
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
            callback.selectedIndustryPosition(position);

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
            int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

            for (int i = firstVisiblePosition; i <= lastVisiblePosition; i++) {
                resetLayoutForPosition(i);
            }
        }
    });
    resetLayoutForPosition(position);
}
```

And you create the method `resetLayoutForPosition` where you set the color as the default case.